# What SEO problems could I run into when changing CMS?

Tags: seo, cms, migration

I have a website on one CMS and I wish to switch to another CMS. What are some problems SEO-wise that I could run into?

I am aware that the way each CMS handles urls is different, so I'll make sure that urls are handled the same:

```
mysite.com/page-about-something

mysite.com/node2
```

**What are some other problems I may face?**

Comment: I suppose that when you say, "urls are handled the same", you mean: urls will be identical.  It doesn't help to have url's which are handled similarly, but still result in different url's ... e.g., dashes instead of underscores, or vice-versa.  If your CMS is good at handling custom url's, you will be able to actually keep the same url's by importing them along with the other things in your porting process.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the urls will be the same. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having migrated a few CMS's before, the URLs are the biggest hurdles.

Some other pain points are:

1. Ensuring content mapping and content layout (in the HTML) isn't radically different - normally achieved by ensuring the templates are the same.
2. Ensuring that meta data is correctly transferred - page titles, meta descriptions and other meta data - this may also include time-stamps for articles.
3. Ensuring categorisation and tags are mapped
4. Ensuring internal links remain in place across templates

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how well the site is linked. If you have links going to abc.com/def.hml and the new is abc.com/xyz.html then you miss the link juice. You can do redirects but that may slow the site down. A few redirects are ok but hundreds or thousands are not. It will hurt site speed. 
I hope this helps. If we had more info it would be better.

As you can see the choice of a CMS is very important.

Comment: The content would have the same urls, no changes there as I would change them all in the CMS before making the site live. Just wondering about issues I would run into other than the url issue.

Comment: The major issue today with CMS is page speed. Some of them are slow. Fast is much better. Many are still evolving.